# Use of "a" with age (numbers) like in "llegar a los cuarenta"

Tags: pronombres, objetos-directos

I am drowning in pronouns here. Can someone help me see the grammar behind the use of the "a los" in the sentence below?

> Gracias, Juan, pero cuando una mujer llega a los cuarenta, comienza a tener otros deseos.

Is it required to be grammatically correct? Can we not just say "... cuando una mujer llega cuarenta..."?

I suspect it would be required because I think it is a direct object pronoun (of llega?), but I am struggling to find good resources that help explain the concept.

Comment: in this case, you have an implicit subject. The phrase is *"Gracias, Juan, pero cuando una mujer llega a los cuarenta (años), comienza a tener otros deseos"*. you can't remove the preposition a and the pronoun los. The phrase *(...)cuando una mujer llega cuarenta años(...)* fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Llegar a** is a multi-word verb, sometimes termed a *phrasal verb*.  (See, for example, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-verbs/verbs-multi-word-verbs.)  Notice that *take off* doesn't have the same meaning as *take*.  Similarly, *llegar a* doesn't have the same meaning as *llegar*.

The exact translation of *llegar a* depends somewhat on the context.  Here's how one dictionary, [spanishdict.com](http://spanishdict.com), defines it:

> **to get to** *Voy a llegar al restaurante un poco atrasado. | I am going to get to the restaurant a little late.*

Here, then, is a natural English version of your sentence:

> Thank you, Juan, but when a woman gets to her forties, she begins to have other desires.

Note that I'm using a possessive pronoun before "forties" in the English version, even though in Spanish there wasn't one, because of the same principle that leads us to say "Me duele **la** cabeza" instead of "Me duele *mi* cabeza."